# How to wait until user close the process in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, subprocess, psutil

I want to create a program that init a new process and then wait until thhis process was killed by user or another program.

But i cant understand why the process create by subprocess is finished after a fraction of time and not by the user closing the process.

```
import subprocess
import psutil

old_process = {p.pid for p in psutil.process_iter()}
calc_process = subprocess.Popen('C:\Windows\System32\calc')
new_process = {p.pid for p in psutil.process_iter()}
process = list(new_process - old_process)[0]

while psutil.pid_exists(process):
    print('Process running')
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

`Popen` has this built in using the [`poll`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) method.

```
from subprocess import Popen

process = Popen('C:\Windows\System32\calc')
process.wait()

while not process.poll():
    print('Process running')

print('Done')
```

Comment: After closing the calculator, the loop still running, so did not work. Besides that, the process create by Popen is not listed in the windows process list ?